# How to compare row with a column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-iq

```
create table TABLE1(
column1 varchar (100),
column2 varchar (100)
)
go
create table TABLE2(
column_for_compare varchar (100)
)
go
insert into TABLE2 values ('column1')
insert into TABLE2 values ('column2')
go
```

I want to check if TABLE1 columns name exists in TABLE2 ,something like this:
--This should be comparing the row values in TABLE2 with column names in TABLE1

if exists(select column_for_compare from TABLE2) and 
if exists(select column_name from syscolumn key join systable where table_name ='TABLE1')
begin
print 'match found'
end

i hope you can see what im trying...if not...if will try to explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table to get the collumn names

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE1'
```

and then join the result with TABLE2

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2, (SELECT column_name
                FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
                WHERE table_name = 'TABLE1') as cNames
WHERE TABLE2.column_for_compare=cNames.column_name
```

This will get you a table with the collumn names in table_1 that exist in the rows in table_2

Answer (score 0):

This query would only return the values in TABLE2 that are columns in TABLE1. You wouldn't be able to a PRINT 'Match Found' without changing the query as you would either need to iterate over each row in TABLE2 or change the query so that you doing a comparison for ALL values in TABLE2.

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    TABLE2
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        ON  TABLE2.column_for_compare = COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME

WHERE
    COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'
```